# What ports does the Watson Discovery Node API and Discovery service use beyond the typical web/SSL ports?

Tags: proxy, ibm-cloud, firewall, ibm-watson

We did a network traffic capture while using the Discovery Node API and found that there was port access attempted on 621XX ports (62111, 62112, etc) and we were wondering if there was a specific set of ports the Discovery service typically uses.

This information would help immensely when firewall and corporate proxy settings come in to play.

Answer (score 1):

The Watson Discovery API is an HTTPS service so only needs TCP port 443 to work. I would suggest that the activity on ports 621** are dynamic or private ports that your app is using to make the connections. They are not ports that need to be punched through firewalls, they are merely the port at which HTTPS connections to the remote server on port 443 are terminated.